# What is the best way to read a file from stdin using bash script and pass the read lines to a python script

Tags: python, bash, stdout, stdin

In my job there is an ancient piece of code written in C, that is called by some other code with the following command:

```
./codeName < fileToRead.in > fileToWrite.out
```

The C code read the fileToRead.in file, perform some tasks and then print its results to the fileToWrite.out.

**The problem:** The thing is that I'm trying to rewrite the C code in Python, but in order to keep the compatibility, the script **must be called exactly the same way**.

**Possible solution:** Since to call python scripts you need to include the ".py" extension, my first thought was to write some bash code, that read the file via stdin, pass the values to a python script, and then write it to the respective file. Keep in mind that I have zero experience with bash scripts, but this piece of code seems to be promising for my task:

```
cat<&0 |
while read a; do    
  # at this point, the current line is associated with $a
  # maybe I can send each line to the python script?
done>&1
```

Finally, is there a way to read the file names provided with the "<" and ">" operators in bash?

Comment: "Since to call python scripts you need to include the ".py" extension" Why? 
Also, as long as the python script reads from stdin and writes to stdout, you could just use it as is.

Comment: To add to that, if you use the correct shebang line, `./codeName` will be enough for it to be run as a Python script.

Comment: @muru I'm not sure if the .py extension is set to the PATHEXT environment variable in all the servers.

Comment: @LuisEduardoBoikoFerreira how does that affect executing a python script in bash? If your python script is named `foo`, has a proper shebang, and is executable, you could run it with `./foo` inCygwin/Msys/WSL bash without worrying about PATHEXT.

Comment: @muru thanks for the answer! I was not aware of this fact!

Answer (score 1):

I can see two sub-problems in your question, so I'm going to try to answer them in a logical order.

First, you want to read in and write out files in python using the `<` and `>` operators on the command line. This should be simple; the shell will handle the piping, so all you have to worry about is the in/out. Let's call this `my_script.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys;
    x = sys.stdin.read()  # read stdin
    print(x)              # write to stdout. You could also use sys.stdout.write()
```

Second, you want to call a python script but you need to use `./script` to do so for compatibility reasons. If that's the case, you can write a *really simple* shell script to just call the python script, call it whatever it needs to be called, and use chmod in advance to set the permissions so that it can be executed by whichever process needs it. Let's just call this file `codeName`. It would need only one line:

```
python my_script.py
```

and then, if you were to execute the following:

```
$ ./codeName < fileToRead.in > fileToWrite.out
```

the pipes for stdin and stdout will still work for the script itself. It would execute the script `codeName`, which would in turn run the command `python my_script.py` which would run the python code, which would read from stdin and write to stdout, *which have been piped from and to `fileToRead.in` and `fileToWrite.out` respectively*.

---

EDIT: Actually, @BenjaminW. makes a good point in his comment. You could skip the extra shell script file and just rename `myscript.py` to `codeName` and give it the correct permissions. You'd just need to add the following line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

which should run the file using the python executable. You may have to change the path to refer to the actual folder that python is located in on your machine.